# facebook iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, fbml

How to add iframe in facebook ,

I tried this snippet but not working...

```
   <a onClick="outside_location.setInnerFBML(link_1);" style="cursor: pointer;">My Form</a>

   <div id="outside_location"></div>
   <fb:js-string var="link_1">
        <fb:iframe height="514" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width:100%;border:none"   src="http://MYNAME.wufoo.com/embed/MYFORM/"><a href="http://happylife.in" title="Contact Request Form" rel="nofollow">Fill out my Wufoo form!</a></fb:iframe>
   </fb:js-string>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var outside_location = document.getElementById('outside_location');
  </script>
```

This is iframe not working....

Answer (score 0):

It won't work unless facebook namespaces are used. See this tutorial on how to create the iframe app:

[Facebook – FBML rendering in IFrame application](http://mahmudahsan.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/facebook-fbml-rendering-in-iframe-application/)